# Ajax Not Loading PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load a PHP file into another PHP file on a click event through Ajax. I'm trying to do this to eliminate loading several modals I have on the page. It seems the PHP file is loading (in the console), but nothing is showing up.

Here's my javascript:

```
    $("a#lightbox-open").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").addClass("noscroll");
    $('section#lightbox').addClass("open");
    $.ajax({
        context: '#lightbox-holder',
        url: '/template/lightbox.inc.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(html){
            alert("works");
        }
    });
});
```

In my main PHP file, I have a div #lightbox-holder that lightbox.inc.php is supposed to load into it.

Comment: Use `success()` instead of `done()` and what exactly is the problem? "nothing is showing up" is quite vague. The alert is empty? `data` is empty? etc

Comment: So does the click event get triggered?

Comment: @kingkero That is incorrect  since `success` is deprecated,

Comment: I updated the code above. The click event is getting triggered.

Comment: When I check out the inspector and look in the Network tab (Chrome), the php file loads, and the classes get added, but the HTML never gets appended into #lightbox-holder

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, didn't know. I still think `success` is more descriptive than `done` though - I mean when the request fails, it still is done, isn't it?

Comment: And yes, data is empty.

Comment: For what it's worth, when I make the files .HTML, it works.

Comment: So is the php actually returning something?

Comment: No it's not. It shows that it loaded the file, but doesn't seem to place the HTML in the loaded file into the #lightbox-holder.

Comment: I have a test link here http://andyrichardson.design/ajax/php/

Comment: I'm simply viewing the inspector > network to view that it's loaded, but there isn't anything there.

Comment: I think it's loading, but not into the div that I want it to load. Is there something else I should be using besides context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context` expects a (Plain)Object (as you can read in the [api doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). Replacing `'#lightbox-holder'` by `$('#lightbox-holder')` will do the trick.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xs05764/) with the `$()` added versus [non working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xs05764/1/) representing your current code.

Comment: So in the fiddle, the URL you have /echo/json, I simply replace with my lightbox.php file? I can't seem to replicate the fiddle.

Comment: @user3817083 That is just for the fiddle to work. Simply replace `context: '...'` by `context: $('...')` in your code and it should work

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems to load the php file, but nothing shows up on screen. When I had it as HTML files, the loaded html was put into the lightbox-holder (if I viewed the inspector > elements).